# Grails - Unable to set the inbuilt database to "update"

Tags: database, grails, database-connection, datasource, h2

I am unable to set my inbuilt database to "`update`". 
It is always cleared when I leave the app, as if still on '`create-drop`'.

It may be useful to know that I was using a MySQL database, and reverted back to in-built database to be able to share the project with some friends whom will not know how to set a SQL database, or a Tomcat server.

Here is my `DataSource.groovy` file:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:myAppDevDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:myAppTestDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:myAppProdDb;MVCC=TRUE"
            pooled = true
            properties {
                maxActive = -1
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
                testOnBorrow=true
                testWhileIdle=true
                testOnReturn=true
                validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your datasource is configured as an in memory datasource so it is discarded when the jvm exits.  If you configure your H2 URL to use a file instead you should be able to save the database.

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:somefile:myAppDevDb;MVCC=TRUE"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Please note using this URL the file 'somefile' will be created in the current working directory where the application is running. It might be safer to use an absolute path, for example `jdbc:h2:/data/db/somefile:myAppDevDb;MVCC=TRUE` or relative to the current user home directory: `jdbc:h2:~/somefile:myAppDevDb;MVCC=TRUE`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It it behaving as expected.